# React, Typescript, Axios consume response?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

How can please write the result of the function in a State?

```
const [car, setCars] = useState<ICars[]>([]);

useEffect(() =>{

  const data = fetchCars(params.cartyp);

  //The return type of this function is:
  Promise<AxiosResponse<ICars[]> | undefined>
  
  setCars(data);  // >> There is an error:

}
```

Error:
TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<ICars[]> | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<ICars[]>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchCars` is async and returns a promise, you have to wait for the results to appear:

```
const [car, setCars] = useState<ICars[]>([]);

useEffect(() =>{

  fetchCars(params.cartyp).then(data => {
    if(data) setCars(data);
  });
  
});
```

Comment: @Alligator usually, [Axios puts the data into a nested property `data`](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema), so in this case, it would be `data.data`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just have to write data.data as the state.